# How do I port-forward 169.254.169.254-bound packets from libvirt/KVM guests to localhost?

Tags: iptables, libvirt

This is a followup to [What's the best way to have a 169.254.169.254 address local to my laptop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73823/whats-the-best-way-to-have-a-169-254-169-254-address-local-to-my-laptop). Short story: 169.254.169.254 is the "well known" address of cloud metadata services for EC2 and for OpenStack, and I want to emulate it on my laptop for devel work.

Having given up on the `lo:0` approach, I decided to just set up NAT/port forwarding. My guests are configured by libvirt, using a default libvirt network which NATs through my wireless nic, which libvirt has configured like so:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.77.0/24     !192.168.77.0/24      masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.77.0/24     !192.168.77.0/24      masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.77.0/24     !192.168.77.0/24
```

This rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 169.254.169.254 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
```

does a lovely job of forwarding from Firefox running on the laptop (host OS) itself. But from within the guest, I get `No route to host`.

Clearly I need something else to make this work. What?

---

As requested, some more networking information. I removed the down interfaces from `ip addr` for brevity.

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:67:20:44:8d:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6267:20ff:fe44:8d48/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 52:54:00:84:3d:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.77.1/24 brd 192.168.77.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.5
192.168.77.0/24 dev virbr1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.77.1
```

---

```
$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

---

```
$ iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.77.0/24     !192.168.77.0/24      masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.77.0/24     !192.168.77.0/24      masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.77.0/24     !192.168.77.0/24
```

---

```
$ iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.77.0/24      ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.77.0/24      0.0.0.0/0          

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 3):

You need DNAT in PREROUTING and maybe also a rule in INPUT but I am not sure whether this can explain the error message. Do you have a route to this network on the host? Any fancy `ip rule` stuff? Please provide the output of `ip addr`, `ip route`, and `ip rule`.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 169.254.169.254 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $local_ip
```

Things probably get a lot easier if you can make this service listen not only on `lo` but also on a non-loopback interface. Say $local_ip should be rather `192.168.77.1` than `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: It all looks pretty boring to me. Since it's Fedora 19, I was using FirewallD, which creates a lot of different (largely empty by default) zones, but I switched that off to simply things (and it doesn't help). The metadata service is listening on all addresess, so it _does_ respond on 192.168.77.1, and in fact I can access it at that address in the guest.

Comment: And, given all that, adding the prerouting DNAT rule does not do it, I'm afraid.

Comment: "I'm afraid" means you tried it and it failed? If so do you see the packets arriving with `tcpdump -i virbr1 -n`?

Comment: Yes, tried and failed. Ahhh! Now that's interesting. I don't get tcp packets, but I _do_ get ARP requests: `20:48:23.758468 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.169.254 tell 192.168.77.82, length 28` (Just that, repeated.)

Comment: Soooo, I added a proxy arp entry:  `arp -s 169.254.169.254 -D virbr1 pub` and the PREROUTING rule started working. Any idea what's up with that? Why does it care?

Comment: @mattdm What are the ARP requests for, 192.168.77.1? Quite strange. Have a look at arp_filter and arp_ignore: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/arp_filter`, `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/arp_ignore`

Comment: No, it's asking who has 169.254.169.254. Which is, of course, nobody. Hmmm -- the _guest_ has a route which says the link-local network (169.254.0.0/16) goes to its eth0 (same as 192.168.77.0/24). That's probably the culprit, although it is out of my control.